# Using parameters to replace mysql fieldnames for prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I am adding a temporary table which contains a list of filenames which a second query will use. I understand that filenames can be used for sql injection, so I want to use prepared statements.

A simplified version of my working query looks like this (e.g. there could be 50 filenames):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempfile(filename varchar(100));
INSERT INTO tempfile (filename) 
    SELECT filename FROM (
        SELECT 'myfile.jpg' AS filename UNION SELECT "myfile2.jpg") xx;
```

I tried to replace it with:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempfile(filename varchar(100));
INSERT INTO tempfile (filename) 
    SELECT filename FROM (
        SELECT ? AS filename UNION SELECT ?) xx;
```

But `mysql` gives me a syntax error. Any ideas how to use parameters with this query?

And if you can give me a better title for this post, I will change it.

**UPDATE - NOTE**

The above query will insert two records. You can then query them with:

```
SELECT tf.filename FROM tempfile
```

Comment: What's the point of `UNION SELECT "myfile2.jpg"`? That will never be inserted.

Comment: @TomasoAlbinoni This query does insert the list of filenames this way into the column `filename`. It's a way to insert table data with a list of known values. The above query will insert the two filenames.

Comment: I stand corrected. I was thrown off by the absence of a column name, but I guess `UNION` takes care of that.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO tempfile (filename)
VALUES
(?),(?),(?);
```

Comment: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempfile(filename varchar(100));INSERT INTO tempfile (filename) VALUES (?),(?); Sql error #: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; Did I miss anything?

Comment: Of course with the above, the next statement was `if (!($stmt = $db->mysqli->prepare($q))) {...}` where `$q` was the query shown.

Comment: Your post helped me find what I was doing wrong. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

I was converting a multi_query to a prepared statement and each statement needed to be run with a separate prepare and execute. Simple and obvious.